# Why I am Getting Follow Issue When I am starting to run JBOSS server in Linux machine?

Tags: jboss

```
>
```

Any can explain me why I am getting this error?.

```
 > 
    > 15:44:52,518 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version
    > 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
    >     15:44:52,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (main) JBAS012017: Starting process 'Host Controll                    
    > er'
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:53,625 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:53,802 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:53,907 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5                    
    > .0.Final-redhat-21) starting
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:54,747 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO Version 3.0.13.GA-redhat-1
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:54,757 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.13                    
    > .GA-redhat-1
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:54,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010902: Creating http management s                   
    > ervice using network interface (management) port (9990) securePort
    > (-1)
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:54,828 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.4.Fin                  
    > al-redhat-1
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:54,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.                     
    > 0.0.1:9999
    >     ****[Host Controller] 15:44:55,695 ERROR [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010932:
    > Caught exc                                                            
    > eption during boot:
    > org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException:
    > JBAS014676: Failed to pa                                              
    > rse configuration
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersi
    > ster.java:141)
    > [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService.boot(DomainModelControllerServ
    > ice.java:503)
    > [jboss-as-host-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:2
    > 63)
    > [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    >     [Host Controller] Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[272,9]
    >     [Host Controller] Message: JBAS014661: Duplicate profile declaration full
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.host.controller.parsing.DomainXml.parseProfiles(DomainXml.java:861)
    > [jboss-                                                               
    > as-host-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.host.controller.parsing.DomainXml.readDomainElement2_0(DomainXml.java:484)
    > [jboss-as-host-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.host.controller.parsing.DomainXml.readElement(DomainXml.java:148)
    > [jboss-as                                                             
    > -host-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.host.controller.parsing.DomainXml.readElement(DomainXml.java:112)
    > [jboss-as                                                             
    > -host-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    > [staxmapper-1.1                                                       
    > .0.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-3]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    > [staxmapper-1.1.                                                      
    > 0.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-3]
    >     [Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersi
    > ster.java:133)
    > [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    >     [Host Controller]       ... 3 more
    >     [Host Controller]
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:55,701 FATAL [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010933:
    > Host Contr                                                            
    > oller boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See
    > previous messages for details.
    >     [Host Controller] 15:44:55,729 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5                    
    > .0.Final-redhat-21) stopped in 19ms
    >     [Host Controller]
    >     15:44:56,049 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (reaper for Host Controller) JBAS012010: Process '                    
    > Host Controller' finished with an exit status of 99****
    >     15:44:56,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process] (Thread-8) JBAS012016: Shutting down process controller
    >     15:44:56,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process] (Thread-8) JBAS012015: All processes finished; exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

Check row 272 in `domain.xml`. It seems you have defined `full` profile twice.

```
>     [Host Controller] Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[272,9]
>     [Host Controller] Message: JBAS014661: Duplicate profile declaration full
```